# How can I print the end result of this method in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, class, methods

Sorry for the admittedly rough title, but I am taking a course for Swift on teamtreehouse.com, and I did a "code challenge" recapping the Object-Oriented Swift course. Anyway, I was provided a couple of classes and my goal was to subclass the Machine class and override the method to actually do something, which I did. I passed the challenge but was curious if I could actually print the end result of this the function after passing in a parameter.

```
class Point {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

class Machine {
    var location: Point

    init() {
        self.location = Point(x: 0, y: 0)
    }

    func move(_ direction: String) {
        print("Do nothing! I'm a machine!")
    }
}

// Enter your code below

class Robot: Machine {
    override func move(_ direction: String) {
        switch direction {
        case "Up": location.y += 1
        case "Down": location.y -= 1
        case "Left": location.x -= 1
        case "Right": location.x += 1
        default: break
        }

    }
}

let aRobot = Robot()
aRobot.move("Up")
print(aRobot.location)
```

So, the final 3 lines are my attempt to actually manage this, but in the console, the line "Point" is printed and not the actual result of the method being enacted. I would like the result to be printed in the form of coordinates if possible. Sorry for the potentially bad code, I am only a beginner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I did manage to figure out a way to get it to print the result by removing the Point class as a whole and changing the stored property location type to `(x: Int, y: Int)` and then doing the same for the init method, but I am still curious is it is possible while still using the Point type

Answer (score 0):

To be able to print a type in swift, you'll want this type to conform to the [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible) protocol. This protocol has only one requirement, to implement a `description` var

```
extension Point: CustomStringConvertible {
 var description: String {
   return "(\(x), \(y))"
 }
}
```

Comment: So would I just implement this code before I attempt to print it?

Comment: Anywhere in the source is fine.